# How to store Gmail messages in Google Drive without using double storage space

Tags: google-drive-api, gmail-api

If you have a Google Account the total amount of space available to you (for free) has been fixed to 15 Gb (at the time being).
How you divide the space between Gmail and Google Drive (and other applications) is up to you.

I would like to store Gmail messages (received) on my Google Drive and be able to see them in Gmail as well WITHOUT using the double amount of storage.
Is this possible? I'm using Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your messages in the native format (Google Document), then the size of the document does not account in your storage quota. That's your best option I think.

You can find more info about this in [this doc from Google](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6558).

In particular, here is what it says about Google Document and quota usage :

> **Items that don't count toward your storage limit**
>
> - Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, Presentations, Drawings, etc.
> - Files that others have shared with you

Comment: If this could be confirmed by someone from Google or by a link to documentation that would be great

Comment: I've added a link to the official documentation

Comment: Basically the docs say that if you store mails in a doc file in Google Drive you will not use storage (quota) even if you delete the Gmail message itself. That's very interesting as it is a way to keep all emails even if their total size exceeds 15 Gb. A pity you can't replace the content of a Gmail message by a link to the Google Drive file automatically or by running a script (AFAIK). At least I know now I should create a script to save emails in Google Drive. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible.